# Java library to transform kanji/katakana/hiragana to romaji

Tags: open-source, library, java, japanese, transliteration

The Japanese language is mostly a combination of 3 alphabets, and it can be [transliterated to romaji (Latin script)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese). There are various strategies, Revised Hepburn would be ideal here.

Example: `ローマ字` → `rōmaji`

Requirements:

- 100% pure Java library
- Compatible with GNU-GPLv3

Such a library will most probably need to embed a lot of data to guess the pronunciations correctly as often as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jakaroma](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/jakaroma) does this, and it is based on [Kuromoji](https://github.com/atilika/kuromoji) which is much better at kanji transliteration than Kakasi and even Mecab.

- 100% Java
- Open source: Apache 2 license
- Size: 11 MB
- Transliteration quality: High

Disclaimer: Maintained by me.

Comment: You should upload it to maven central. Also, from what I can see Jakaroma only exposes transliteration from kana to romaji? What would I go about transliterating kanji to kana or romaji?

Answer (score 2):

[Kakasi Java](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/kakasi-java) does exactly this.
It also includes a command-line tool so that you can easily try it.

- 100% Java
- Open source: GNU-GPLv2 license
- Size: 3.2 MB
- Transliteration quality: Poor

Disclaimer: Maintained by me.

Note: [Mecab](http://taku910.github.io/mecab/) is more accurate at guessing pronunciations but is not 100% Java unfortunately.